# How can I convert a duration/timer to hex?

Tags: timer, hex

I've come across a screenshot of a certain software, showing the a device's life timer like this: "96B80300 <> 000067:44". The software is not open source, it's an unofficial tool for older Nokia devices.

My question is, how do you get from "000067:44" to the "96B80300" hex value?

I am trying to change a similar timer on another device (uses only 7 digits though, like "00000:00"), and this info could be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a possible indication. If 67:44 represents hours and minutes, then the number of seconds in hex would be 67 * 60 * 60 + 44 * 60 = 243840 => 0x03B880, which allowing for big/little/whatever endian, means that it is missing 0x96 - 0x80 = 0x16 or 22 seconds. Perhaps the seconds are just not being displayed in decimal.